# Is the half installation issue just related to my desktop?

Tags: qgis, installation

I have tried to install QGIS version 3.16 on to my work computer (I am working remotely from home) and it asked me to uninstall a programme which was apparently already on the system (I think it may have been QGIS 3.16). I clicked yes, but halfway through I was concerned that I may be deleting colleague files, so I stopped the process. Now I am unable to open some QGIS based files (I think they may have only been half installed) and I'm just wondering if there's a way to rectify this, and whether this will have affected my colleagues QGIS software too?

Comment: Asking a colleague is probably the best way to see if you've mangled the install on the server.

Comment: In the end, you will probably have to reinstall QGIS. But if your colleagues use the same work computer that you do you should certainly check with them before you do anything else.

Comment: You will need to reinstall > unless you have virtual machine snapshots (or equivalent?)\